# Django. Как сделать зависимый выпадающий список с помощью JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, django, search

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если не сложно, как правильно написать скрипт, чтобы при выборе региона отображались города только этого региона, а при выборе города - районы только этого города. Мне это нужно для поиска по сайту.

Модели:

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название области')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Область')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название города')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class District(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Город')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название района')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Функция поиска во views.py:

```
def search(request):
    districts = District.objects.all()
    cities = City.objects.all()
    regions = Region.objects.all()
    queryset_list = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date')

    if 'region' in request.GET:
        region_id = request.GET.get('region')
        cities = City.objects.filter(region_id=region_id).order_by('name')
        if region_id:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(region_id=region_id)

    if 'city' in request.GET:
        city_id = request.GET.get('city')
        districts = District.objects.filter(city_id=city_id).order_by('name')
        if city_id:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(city_id=city_id)

    if 'district' in request.GET:
        district_id = request.GET.get('district')
        if district_id:
            queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(district_id=district_id)

    context = {
        'districts': districts,
        'cities': cities,
        'regions': regions,
        'listings': queryset_list,
        'values': request.GET
    }
    return render(request, 'listings/search.html', context)
```

Благодаря этой функции весь список регионов, городов и районов динамически отображается в шаблоне, поиск также работает, но необходимо, чтобы выбор был зависимым.

Вот search.html:

```
             <form action="{% url 'search' %}">    
               <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">                  
                  <label class="sr-only">Region</label>
                  <select name="region" class="form-control" id="id_region">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Region</option>
                    {% for region in regions %}
                      <option value="{{ region.pk }}">{{ region.name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">City</label>
                  <select name="city" class="form-control" id="id_city">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">City</option>
                      {% for city in cities %}
                        <option value="{{ city.pk }}">{{ city.name }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </div>                
                <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                  <label class="sr-only">District</label>
                  <select name="district" class="form-control" id="id_district">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">District</option>
                      {% for district in districts %}
                        <option value="{{ district.pk }}">{{ district.name }}</option>
                      {% endfor %}
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
             <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-block mt-4" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
```

Я знаю, что это делается на JS, но я пока в совсем новичок в этом, поэтому, если не сложно, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь пример, как будет выглядеть скрипт в моей ситуации? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: По клику на селект выбора области отправляете запрос на сервер, там его обрабатываете и возвращаете json клиенту. Аналогично с городом. Хотя, возможно, есть более изящное решение.

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, какой-нибудь пример простенький?

Comment: Здесь есть пример https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dx6uXEuPtw4&list=PLp_WN118C-VdgBKf_ATbvGI1xX06dZkmF&index=21

Comment: Спасибо. Буду смотреть.